# Pyhton exercise : Raise the exception SyntaxError if s is NOT in the format specified above

Tags: python, raiseerror

I am doing an excercise on codio where I am asked to

Raises the exception SyntaxError if s is NOT in the format specified above
Raises the exception ValueError if s is in the format above, but penalty is a greater number than mark

Now the code below works perfectly fine, I am sure that I am not too far, but missing something

when I test my code in codio I get the following

```
FAIL: test_2 (test_calculate_mark.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/codio/workspace/.guides/secure/calculate_mark/test_calculate_mark.py", line 17, in test_2
    calculate_mark("john xx 30")
AssertionError: SyntaxError not raised : ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

WE TRIED:
`calculate_mark("john xx 30")` and did not get `SyntaxError` exception

```
def calculate_mark(s):

  mystring= s.split()

  m=s.replace(" ", "")
  try:
    
    assert m.isdigit() == True, "SyntaxError"
    student_number=(mystring[0])
    student_mark=int((mystring[1]))
    student_penanlty=int((mystring[2]))
    assert student_penanlty <student_mark , "ValueError"
    mycalc=student_mark-student_penanlty
    final_mark=student_number + " "+  str(mycalc)
    return final_mark

  except AssertionError as msg:
    print(msg)



calculate_mark("123 35 50")
```

Comment: As Nils says, you use `raise` to raise an exception, not `assert`.  This applies to BOTH your uses of `assert` here.  And you certainly don't want to use `try/except` if your test app needs to catch your exception.

Comment: The second argument to `assert` is the *reason* which is included in the AssertionError that's raised. That is, if you print `str(msg)` you will get the reason you have specified (for ex. 'SyntaxError' as specified above)

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually `raise` the Exception:

```
raise SyntaxError()
```

and to clean it all up

```
def calculate_mark(s):
    splits = s.split()

    try:
        splits = [int(s) for s in splits]
    except ValueError:  # at least one of splits is not an integer
        raise SyntaxError("Please pass exactly three integer strings")

    number, mark, penalty = splits

    if penalty < mark:
        raise ValueError("penalty must be larger than mark")
    
    return f"{number} {mark - penalty}"

print(calculate_mark("123 35 50"))
```

Comment: Don't ever compare to True.  Just write `if not m.isdigit():`.

Comment: Oops yes you're right, I just blindly copied what was in the Q.